# What headers to use with nike api?

Tags: python, api, nikeplus-api

I am interested in making some script that will be working by using `https://api.nike.com/`, but I dont know how to work with it and all information that I found was relevant for ~2017 year

So, how can I find out what headrs should I use or maybe there is even documentation?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm also looking for any information on https://api.nike.com/ , do you have any idea of any url params? The only thing i got working in postman is: 
https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1?queryid=filteredProducts&anonymousId=25AFE5BE9BB9BC03DE89DBE170D80669&uuids=0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550,16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c&language=en-GB&country=BG&channel=NIKE&localizedRangeStr=%7BlowestPrice%7D%E2%80%94%7BhighestPrice%7D